# sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN); doesn't work with viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I used to have my scrollview scroll down initiatively using (in my onCreate):

```
    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
    sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }, 100L);
```

But ever since I included a viewpager with a fragmentpageadapter this doesn't work anymore.
I can't seem to find out why it doesn't, and also can't find a working alternative.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work anymore', what do you mean? In which way it doesn't work?

Comment: Right now, the application stops working if I put the code back in, even though it worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply full scroll in viewpager, you could use setCurrentItem method. here you go :

```
yourviewPager.setCurrentItem(lastPosition, true);
```

flag "true" stands for smoothScroll.